# Unsubscribe in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, unsubscribe

I'm new to rxjs.
what is the problem with this code that subscribe method not work correctly.

```
this.http.postReq(this.api, data)
.subscribe((value) => {
  this.toastr.success(value, "Successfull");
  this.isLoading = false;
}, (err) => {
  this.toastr.error(err.error, "Error")
  this.isLoading = false;
}).unsubscribe();
```

}

but when remove ".unsubscribe()" its work correctly.

[an example that work correctly in this manner.](https://jsbin.com/copujo/4/edit?js,console)

Comment: the call is asynchronous so , your request is unsubscribed even before getting the response.

Comment: how can i unsubscribe async request

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe here. Angular's HttpClient, which I assume you are using, completes the observable when the response is sent. A completed observable cleans up after itself automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this :

```
let someSubscription = this.http.postReq(this.api, data)
.subscribe((value) => {
  this.toastr.success(value, "Successfull");
  this.isLoading = false;
someSubscription.unsubscribe();
}, (err) => {
  this.toastr.error(err.error, "Error")
  this.isLoading = false;
});
```

So now , your request is unsubscribed after getting the response (which you want) .